# Image not popping up

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I am very new to React and I am trying to get an image of a shirt onto the website. No error pops up, but the shirt just doesn't show up. Here is my 'index.jsx':

```
    import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber';
    import { Environment, Center } from '@react-three/drei';

    import Shirt from './Shirt';
    import Backdrop from './Backdrop';
    import CameraRig from './CameraRig';

    const CanvasModel = () => {
      return (
        <Canvas>
          <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
          <Environment preset='city' />

          <CameraRig>
            <Backdrop />
            <Center>
              <Shirt />
            </Center>
          </CameraRig>
        </Canvas>
      )
    }

    export default Canvas
```

This is what my 'Shirt.jsx' looks like:

```
    import React from 'react'
    import { easing } from 'maath';
    import{ useSnapshot } from 'valtio';
    import { useFrame } from '@react-three/fiber';
    import { Decal, useGLTF, useTexture } from '@react-three/drei';
    import state from '../store';

    const Shirt = () => {
      const snap = useSnapshot(state);
      const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('/shirt_baked.glb');

      const logoTexture = useTexture(snap.logoDecal);
      const fullTexture = useTexture(snap.fullDecal);
  
      return (
        <group>
          <mesh
            castShadow
            geometry={nodes.T_Shirt_male.geometry}
            material={materials.lambert1}
            material-roughness={1}
            dispose={null}
          >

          </mesh>
        </group>
      )
    }

    export default Shirt
```

I can't seem to find the error. I feel like I mistyped something but I can't see it.